# Setting a dropdown's value by HTML

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'd like to select a dropdown list's value by its HTML. For example, I have the following selections...

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
</select>
```

Right now I am able to retrieve the text **Choice 1**. I understand that I can select the corresponding value using `$('#dropdown').val('1');`. However, I don't actually have access to 1, and I'd like to select that same selection just using **Choice 1**.

Is this possible via jQuery, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#dropdown option').each(function() {
  if($(this).text()=='yourvalue') $('#dropdown').val($(this).val());
});
```

Iterate through the options and check the corresponding value

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Zwx/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this working jsfiddle  link. http://jsfiddle.net/Fh3WC/

Replace hard coded Choice 1 with your variable value.

```
$(function() {
    $("select option:contains('Choice 1')").attr('selected','selected');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* get value */
document.getElementById("dropdown").options[0].value

/* get text */
document.getElementById("dropdown").options[3].text
```

Comment: his question was how to select an option by its content, not by its index.